# Отслеживание личных сообщений discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Возможно ли сделать такую функцию в боте для Discord на discord.py, которая будет отслеживать сообщения написанные боту в личном чате?
То есть когда участник присутствующий на сервере с ботом пишет боту в личном чате сообщения бот получал их и заносил в переменную.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бот есть в общем канале, то он будет реагировать на все события и команды. Просто создайте ивент on_message, добавьте бота в общий канал и пишите ему в личку.